# iOS 13 WiFi Sync location

Tags: ios, finder, wifi, data-synchronization

Previously (before iOS 13) I was able to attempt to begin a WiFi sync from my phone by going to Settings > General > Wifi Sync

I no longer see that option. On my computer (currently on macOS 10.15) I'm at the mercy of the phone showing up in the Finder (just as I used to be at the mercy of it showing up in iTunes) whenever that strikes the phone or the computer's fancy (I'm unable to determine what makes it appear or not.)

Is there a way to tell the phone to begin a sync? (or alternatively tell Finder to look and show me the phone which is connected to the same WiFi network and ready to go if it would just show up ok Finder)

Comment: Does your wifi allow such visibility?  I have a faint memory of a discussion where router was not configured to allow network discovery.

Comment: Yep it has connected and synced. The phone just seems to show up (or not show up) at random.

Answer (score 1):

After iOS 13 and Mac OS Catalina, it seems that Apple needs to introduce a helper utility to pair the device.

I’m an iOS developer and we use Xcode’s built in utility to pair and unpair devices.

Sometimes the device doesn’t get automatically connected so we have to connect it via a fixed IP address.

```
Open Xcode (can be downloaded free)
Open devices and simulators
Connect via IP
```

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458481/797819).

Answer (score 0):

*Ankii* mentions [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT210612) which states:

> When the computer and the device are on the same Wi-Fi network, the device appears in iTunes. The device syncs automatically whenever  plugged in to power and iTunes is open on the computer.

Comment: iTunes is no longer a part of macOS as of 10.15

Comment: That is basically how it works now but with Finder instead of iTunes. I’m looking for a way to move things along when both devices ARE on the same WiFi and the phone isn’t showing up in Finder.

Comment: So, before, we had to plug the iPad into power, then go to the computer and open iTunes.  Silly—might as well take the iPad to the computer and plug it in there. Now, seems there’s another problem: Finder is always open, unless logged out.  Yet mine still is not syncing unless I walk to the computer and click sync button in Finder.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210611).

Following these steps work for me.  The Apple page was referenced in an earlier answer however the steps to enable it were not mentioned.

## Sync your content using Wi-Fi

**After you set up syncing with the Finder using USB**, you can set up the Finder to sync to your device with Wi-Fi instead of USB.

1. Connect your device to your computer with a USB cable, then open a Finder window and select your device.
2. Select “Show this [device] when on Wi-Fi" and "Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected".

[image]

3. Click Apply.

When the computer and the device are on the same Wi-Fi network, the device appears in the Finder. **The device syncs automatically whenever it's plugged in to power**.

Comment: as I understand OP has done such sync first, but it is unreliable. It doesn't work when they want it to and they want to force sync or force rescan the network for the device.

Comment: OP didn't mention if the followed the initial setup so I wanted to be sure.  From my research, the iPhone will not sync if there's nothing to sync since the last connection.  I'm not able to find a way to force a sync at this time.

Comment: ah yes.. I too had to interpret from comments. Some workarounds to do a rescan are similar to turn off wifi on both and turn back on. Idk who can guarantee for that.

Comment: Thanks, I did the initial pairing via USB... It looks like it is doing an alright job of automatically syncing over WiFi... I would just like to be able to reliably push a button on my computer (or phone) to do a sync *now* (e.g. if I'm about to go on a road trip and want my playlists updated.)

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  I didn't find any info regarding a manual or on-demand wifi sync.